# Loading and saving textbox values on switching the radio button C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, radio-button

I'm building an application with c# on Visual Studio 2017. My interface consist of several textboxes and two radio buttons. Each time, the app is being closed, I save the values of the textboxes to two separate text files. So as the result I have two text files (for each radio button). Each time the radio button is being checked, I load the textbox values from the appropriate txt file. This is how its implemented now:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] boxes = { textBoxAscStart, textBoxAscStep };
        loadConfigFile(boxes);
    }


private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] boxes = { textBoxAscStart, textBoxAscStep };
        loadConfigFile(boxes);
    }


private void loadConfigFile(TextBox[] boxes) {
        try
        {
            string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string fullName;
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                fullName = dir + "\\Config1.txt";
            }
            else
            {
                fullName = dir + "\\Config2.txt";
            }
            char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@fullName))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] line = file.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
                    boxes[i].Text = line[1];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I understand I implement this in dummy way, so sorry for my poor code. Such approach works fine until you mostly work on one of radiobuttons checked and then exit the app so the values are written to file. But how I can implement the case when user works on one radiobutton and then switches to another (with another values), works a bit there and gets back? In my case he will still see those old values from text file. I want that each time the user gets back to previous radio button, the values in the textboxes would be the latest he entered. I hope I was clear enough. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Cache them, in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If I got correctly what you asked is that you want the user to have the new text in the textbox when he switches between radiobuttons. If so:

> I think you should modify `CheckedChanged` events for both radiobuttons and add a function
>   that gets the actual text from the textbox and compares it with  the data
>   you have already saved in the text file. If it's different then save
>   it and use that new text for the radio buttons to display, because you got new text. If it's the same just use `loadConfigFile(boxes);`  Hope the logic helps you :)